# How to limit specific emails being inserted into database?

Tags: php, mysql

I was just searching for the most proficient way to only allow a specific email to be inserted into my database only one time, upon a user creating an account with their unique email. I'm assuming it's a simple if statement that triggers an error message if attempted.

Is this only possible via php or is there a mysql shortcut to accomplish this?

Comment: What emails? How to you get them? How do you decide which emails you want and which you don't?

Comment: I'm sorry, that was a little unclear. When a user is creating an account, I want to allow a specific email only once.

Comment: why is this a bad question? I really am ok with the downvote, but I think people should explain as opposed to just blindly pulling the trigger. I can learn from my mistakes that way.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but you usually have to show that you've actually attempted to solve the issue by explaining what you've tried so far and what the errors were, etc. See the FAQ for more info.

Comment: your question is unclear - i suspect that's why the downvoting.  'email' can be taken very literally - what you are asking is about stroing an 'email address' in the database uniquely.

Comment: Yes, what @Randy said as well - email address has nothing to do with this (that's why I removed the tag), it could be just anything that needs to have no duplicates.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the UNIQUE index to the email field in the database.
See [this](http://php.about.com/od/mysqlcommands/g/add_unique.htm).

---

UPDATE

Ok, so now that you've explained your problem a bit more accurately, I'd suggest you still keep the email field `UNIQUE` in the database, but add some user-friendly notifications for users trying to create an account using an existing email address. You can do this like showing them a popup saying that the address is already in use, suggest them to reset the password in case they've forgotten it, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want unique email address in your database table, then create a unique index on the field in which you are storing the email address.  This will automatically prevent any duplicates from being inserted into the table.

At the application layer it would be best practice to either check the DB for a record before inserting a new record, or simply trying to insert the record into the database and handling any error that results from trying to insert a duplicate key.

Personally I prefer the latter, as in most cases only a single query on the DB is needed (the insert query), and I handle DB error conditions in all cases anyway, so simply adding a little logic to determine if the error was due to a duplicate key insert attempt is pretty simple.